# Can't get a connection between file upload form to a localhost route (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file-upload, multer

I've been using [this tuturial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-allow-users-to-upload-images-with-node-express-mongoose-and-cloudinary-84cefbdff1d9/) to upload an image from a user to a Cloudinary 
server. 
Yet I can't even get the connection to my backend.

I'm using this form :

```
 <form action='/api/images' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
 <input type='file' name='image' /></form>
```

To get to this route :

```
router.post('/api/images', parser.single("image"), (req, res) => {
console.log("ok")
console.log(req.file)
})
```

As the tuturial suggests but I can't even get to the console log "ok" after I choose a file. What am I missing?

Comment: is your front end being served from the same node server where your api is running?

Comment: Yes they both are on localhost:8000. It's a React app if it makes any change